# dropdownextender Ajax tool kit

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax

**How to implement in dropdownextender to go to the selected item by keyboard or go to items starting with 'A' when i press 'A' on my keyboard, i need it work as a normal drop down control.**
good reference i got from it good ideas:
*http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=167*

Answer (score 1):

On the following page, the dropdown seems to have the functionality I think you are looking for.

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ListSearch/ListSearch.aspx

Something like this should work:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="100px" />

<ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender ID="ListSearchExtender2" runat="server"
     TargetControlID="DropDownList1" PromptCssClass="ListSearchExtenderPrompt"
     QueryPattern="Contains" QueryTimeout="2000">
</ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender>
```